# How to remove a loading gif when 3rd party iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have following code to show and hide a loading GIF while waiting for a 3rd party iframe:

**HTML**

```
<div id="waitmessage" class="hide"><img src="/static/images/global/wait.gif"/></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.iframe').ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#waitmessage').removeClass('hide');
            alert('skywalker');
        });
    });
    $('.iframe').load(function () {
    $('#waitmessage').remove();
});
```

But when the iframe is loaded, the gif is still loading in background. 
The iframe is an overlay on main page btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you're waiting for `.iframe` to be ready and the selector doesn't have such event fired, assuming the selector return null because the DOM hasn't loaded yet. So anything inside the `.ready` event handler will not be executed. The right way to wait for DOM to load is used predefined variable `document`. Try this.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#console').text( $('#console').text()+"\r\n"+'DOM is ready');
    $('#yt').on('load', function(){
       console.log('YouTube loaded');
       $('#console').text( $('#console').text()+"\r\n"+'YouTube loaded');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="console"></pre>
<iframe id="yt" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AhhEYe5Hczo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```